# O365 Graph Subscriptions - Not receiving notifications for subscriptions on user mailfolder updates and deletes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to use the microsoft graph api to setup a [subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0) for a user's mailfolders for the `changeType` of `updated, deleted` with the `resource` of `/me/mailfolders` (synonymous with `/users/{id}/mailfolders`. The subscription creates successfully, but when i move folders around in the outlook client, or delete folders, no notifications are received on my notification  client.

Am asking this stackoverflow question as per troubleshooting instructions in [Microsoft's guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-sample/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md).

Wondering if this is a supported resource? And if so, why no notifications are being received?

Subscription ID: 78b8a9a5-083e-427d-b7e0-95c0f5cffdda

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#resources-examples) you cannot create subscription for mail folder but only for changes to all messages in a user's mailbox or for changes to messages in a user's Inbox.

```
/me/messages
/users/{id}/messages
/me/mailFolders('inbox')/messages
/users/{id}/mailFolders('inbox')/messages
```